# Cast listviewitem to System.IConvertible

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, iconvertible

I have following issue... I got a listview in which I have some numbers (ID's). Now I want to arrange them with some listboxes so that I can do a typical SQL search (with OR, AND). So the listview gets filled that way:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < simIdCells.Count; i++)
            {
                ListViewItem store = new ListViewItem(simIdCells[i]);
                store.SubItems.Add(simNameCells[i]);
                form5.listViewCap.Items.Add(store);
                form5.listViewCap.Items[0].Selected = true;
                form5.listViewCap.Select();
            }
```

So there is always a value selected in my listview. When I now want to do the search I use this code to first fill my elements into a list:

```
   foreach(var selectedItem in listView1.SelectedItems)
        {
           simIdElements.Add(Convert.ToInt32(selectedItem));
        }
```

Now I get the following exception:

> object of type "System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem" can not be
>   converted to the type "System.IConvertible".

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: As the error is trying to tell you, it makes no sense to convert a ListViewItem to a number.

Comment: Yes but there must be a way to convert that to an integer or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ListViewItem cannot be converted to integer. You should either convert back item text to int or use it's [Tag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.tag%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to keep the integer value with the item.

First approach:

```
foreach(ListViewItem selectedItem in listView1.SelectedItems)
{
     string text = selectedItem.Text;
     simIdElements.Add(Convert.ToInt32(text));
}
```

Second approach:

```
for (int i = 0; i < simIdCells.Count; i++)
{
    int value = simIdCells[i];
    ListViewItem store = new ListViewItem(value.ToString());
    store.Tag = value;
    ListViewItem subItem = new istViewItem(value.ToString());
    subItem.Tag = value;
    store.SubItems.Add(subItem);
    form5.listViewCap.Items.Add(store);
    form5.listViewCap.Items[0].Selected = true;
    form5.listViewCap.Select();
}
...
...
foreach(var selectedItem in listView1.SelectedItems)
{
    simIdElements.Add((int)selectedItem.Tag);
}
```

Comment: He tells me that there is no .Text for the type object in the first approach and there was no .Tag found for object in the second approach

Comment: try replacing var with ListViewItem in the for loop.

Comment: Now I get a NullReferenceException at the .Tag. selectedItem has a value but Tag is null

Comment: Which approach you are using? You need to use only one of them only. I updated the answer again for  the second approach.

Comment: Ok I now used the first one but I changed it a bit to           foreach (ListViewItem selectedItem in listView1.SelectedItems)
            {
                simIdElements.Add(Convert.ToInt32(selectedItem.Text));
            } and now it works! Thanks for the solution with the .Text!